# Bootstrap navbar center item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, center, navbar

I have a navbar and I would like to center my search field but I don't find which classes I'm supposed to use. Is there some other documentation than the official website ? I would have a list of all classes and what they do, it's not possible?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PrivateChat</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pseudo <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Profil</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Déconnexion</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my revised answer:

```
.navbar-center
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

And

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-center" role="search">
```

Working example:
http://www.bootply.com/XS8FA919dX

Comment: it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: thank U,,,,I add css padding-top: 7px; and looks like more charm.

Comment: @DanielG, if wrap the suggested CSS in `@media (min-width: 768px) {  ... }`, then it works fine on collapse as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that simply like this if you are using bootstrap 4

```
<form class="navbar-form d-flex justify-content-center w-100" role="search"></form>
```

this is also equivalent to this:

```
.navbar-center  {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: For people working with Bootstrap 4.5+
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/migration/#navbar
navbar-form is not longer used.